# Mysql 8.0: How to Alter Procedure Definer

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, alter, mysql-8.0

We easily update routines/SP definer till 5.7 but in 8.0 we are not able to find the exact command. I am running below but not working. And please also note that we can't generate script and update it manually and then re-execute the script. We have around 3500 SP's in live and we can't afford any downtime. Is there any work around?

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE sng.sp_get_profile_search_2_test SQL SECURITY
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
```

or

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE sng.sp_get_profile_search_2_test SQL SECURITY
DEFINER='root'@'localhost'
```

Comment: You can't change the definer name, you can only change `SQL SECURITY` as `DEFINER or INVOKER`, [mysql-docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-procedure.html)

Answer (score -1):

**Try this :**

```
UPDATE sng.sp_get_profile_search_2_test SET DEFINER = 'dbname@localhost';
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near